# Prior after variable transformation

Tags: prior, posterior, transform

I am sampling the variables ($\alpha, \beta, \gamma$) with a Markov chain where I put the priors to be flat, e.g. $\pi(\alpha) = U(\alpha)$ and similarly for $\beta, \gamma$.

Now I am actually interested in $\theta = \frac{\gamma}{f(\beta)}$. Computing the transformation of the posterior probability gives:
$P(\theta) = P(\gamma) | \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \gamma} | = P(\gamma)f(\beta) $

What I am not sure is how to deal with the prior, if I want a uniform prior in $\theta$ and not $\gamma$. From Bayes theorem I have:
$P(\gamma) = \mathcal{L}(\gamma) \pi(\gamma) Z(\gamma)^{-1} $

How to recover
$P(\theta) = \mathcal{L}(\theta) \pi(\theta) Z(\theta)^{-1} $
where $\pi(\theta) = U(\theta)$ ?

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you are asking about mathematical theory or how to implement this change-of-variables in a sampling script? And if you are asking how to do this in an example, please tell us what software and packages you are using.

Comment: Your transform is not a bijection hence you cannot apply the change-of-variable formula.

Comment: @Wesley: I already have the posterior after sampling and I am implementing the change of variable myself, so more about mathematical theory.

Comment: @Xi'an: for some part of the variable space and some functions $f(\beta)$, it can be a bijection no?